# Microsoft Edge HLS support and other browsers

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge supports HLS, but there are browsers that don't (e.g. Chrome). I read that to test the availability of HLS you have to test the video.src this way:

```
videoPromise = video.play()

if(videoPromise !== undefined){
    // There's support
} else {
    // There's no support
}
```

This code is to offer an alternative to HLS if there's no support, but when this code is used in Edge, `video.play` returns `undefined` and therefore breaking other expected calls.

A possible alternative is to use `video.onplay` and `video.onplaying` to actually find out in all browsers that the video plays, and be sure that it plays the HLS video.

Is there a better way to verify this in Edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't want to do it this way ever, as the latest spec has  `play()` return a promise, which will never not be truthy (a rejected promise, indicating a lack of support, is not undefined and therefore will still pass your if statement).

There is actually a built in way to check if a video type is supported, in `canPlayType`. This is built off of any media element (i.e. <audio> and <video>), you just pass the mimetype for the content you want to play. For most HLS content, you would use `application/x-mpegURL`. Since the media element doesn't have to be in the DOM for this to function, you could write this like so

```
var supported = document.createElement('video').canPlayType('application/x-mpegURL')

if (supported) {
  // There's support
} else {
  // There's no support
}
```